# User Friendly Git Revision Numbers?

Tags: git, google-code

I am using Git for a coding project on Google Code.

How do I get the revision numbers to be something meaningful like `Alpha v1.0` or `r86` instead of `d68838463ecf` or other jumble like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All git commits are given a cryptographically secure sha1 tag like the one you pasted. If you are looking to label a specific commit you should use git tag and tag the commit with whatever label you so choose.

```
git tag "Release 1.0" 1f42f25b0e
```

Because git is distributed, there was no way for it to use synchronous commit numbers (like SVN) without all distributions having to communicate with each other. Additionally, a sufficiently long string was required to mathematically ensure commit name uniqueness. This is why a sha1 is used as the unique name of the commit, but you are allowed to label via tags on top.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to use tags to achieve that? I'm pretty new to git/source control.

Comment: Edited my answer to include. As a rule of thumb, I find git's help docs to be superb. when in doubt, git <cmd> --help usually has exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned, there's no way to get incrementing 'pretty' revision numbers with Git. If you want that and DVCS, turn to [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). However, note that Mercurial incrementing revisions are just a local convenience notation.

As for git, it shoudn't influence your version numbering scheme. You can creat your own version number scheme that's hopefully sane, and tag commits accordingly. When you have reached version 1.0, for example, tag the commit:

```
$ git tag -a v1.0
```

This will apply an annotated tag to the current `HEAD` of your branch. You should always use an annotated tag for this purpose unless you know what you're doing.

This creates the tag, and now `git describe` will tell you this:

```
$ git describe
v1.0
```

Now, where things get interesting is if you commit something else and are no longer pointing to the tag. Then, `git describe` is still useful:

```
$ git describe
v1.0-1-g9f52f48
```

Now, `git describe` will give you a unique friendlier identifier for an intermediate commit between tags. The notation above indicates the nearest tag, the number of commits beyond it, and the short hash of the actual commit being described.

So, using `git describe` and annotated tagging is an easy way to always provide a unique version number with git, and is akin to something like using subversion's revision as your build identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git-tag to do that.

`git tag yourTag1.0 ed851a...<-The second param is the commit hash you want to tag`

To see the tag you can do the following

`git log --decorate`

You might get something like the following

```
commit ed851a7107f457935b0c6f75c4458116024a37e2 (HEAD, tag: myTag1.8, master)
Author: Jerry test <Jerry.test@test.com>
Date:   Wed May 2 16:47:11 2012 -0400

    testing
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you have to tag anything you want to identify as a "release". If your model is more "continuous-release" (as in the code committed to the repo should always be release-worthy) this is not ideal.

Comment: @KeithS, things break even during continuous-release models don't they? If you tagged something, and it turns out it was broken, you can retag another commit after fixing it with no problem. You can just move the tag around.

Answer (score 0):

As the Git revision ID is hexadecimal, you can convert it to a decimal number (your example would parse out to 235880548024015) and then modulus it into a build number that you can use in a ver.sub.rev.build versioning scheme. However, as Ben said, it's a SHA1 hash; as such it's subject to "avalanche effect" where a small change to the input makes a huge change to the output. As such, build numbers generated from the revision won't be sequential.